enable tagging for azure alert rules and option to filter based on the tags
I am using below ARM template  azureDevops task automation to create many alert rules across our environments.
ADO task as below
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2            
                      inputs:
                        azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
                        action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                        resourceGroupName: $(${{ variables.podnamerg }})
                        location: 'xxxxx'
                        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
                        csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm-source-development-${{ alert.AlertRuleName }}/numofresult_template.json '
                        csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/arm-source-development-${{ alert.AlertRuleName }}/numofresult_param.json'

ARM as below
"resources":[
    {
        "type":"Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
        "name": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",            
        "properties":{
            "displayName": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
            "description": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
            "enabled": "[parameters('enabled')]",
            "source": {
                "query": "[parameters('query')]",
                "dataSourceId": "[parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceId')]",
                "queryType":"ResultCount"
            },
            "schedule":"[parameters('schedule')]",
            "action":{
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                "severity": "[parameters('severity')]",
                "aznsAction":{
                    "customWebhookPayload": "{ \"AlertRuleName\":\"#alertrulename\", \"AlertType\":\"#alerttype\", \"Severity\":\"#severity\", \"Application\":\"#{appname}#\", \"Text\":\"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records. #{alertDescription}#\", \"SearchQuery\":\"#searchquery\" }",
                    "actionGroup": "[array(parameters('actionGroupName'))]"
                },
                "trigger":{
                    "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('operator')]",
                    "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

By using above we have 1000+ alert rules create already. Now I have a requirement to disable specific alert rules from the already created alert rules, so this will look up all the alert rules dynamically and filter the alert rules which I want specifically and disable them.
So if i add tags to each alert rules which i need to filter, whether i can dynamically filter those alert rule and disable over command ? I couldnt find a slution filter alert rules with specific tags.

Are you trying to filter it only with the ARM or any CLI or PowerShell approach works for you! @Vowneee

preferring cli based Bash script

Will work on it and update here. @Vowneee

To disable the scheduled query alert rules, you can use either CLI or PowerShell script. As you mentioned the requirement is preferably CLI bash script, check below script with the relevant Az CLI commands.
Firstly, I have verified whether the given query alert exists in my environment and stored my query rule output further in a Json file as shown.
az  monitor scheduled-query list --resource-group caronew o json > myrules.json


Note: You can see the highlighted enabled option which is set to true after execution.
After that, I have filtered it with the given tags by using
--query parameter along with the az monitor scheduled-query list command.
az monitor scheduled-query list --resource-group caronew --query "[?tags.alertrule=='first']"


Now to disable it, I have used az monitor scheduled-query update CLI command with the
--set enabled=false argument as shown below. I have looped it with for for automated executions.
Note: Alternatively, you can set --disabled to true along with the az monitor scheduled-query update command.
rg="caronew"
for scheduledrule in $(jq -r '.[].name' myrules.json); 
do
  az monitor scheduled-query update --name $scheduledrule --resource-group $rg --set enabled=false
done


The relevant PowerShell approach for the above requirement is Update-azscheduledqueryrule command.
References: Manage-alert-processing-rules,
az monitor scheduled-query create

I already have these commands to disable and enable the alerts. But what i am looking is, a way to to pick the alert rules using tags , and iterate those alert rules to disable. I have a automation to pass the alert rule name and disable it the same way as you shared above. But what i needed is a dynamic way to filter alert rules with tags and disable them all.

Ya even I have given code for the same. Picking the alert rule based on the specific tag and disabling it. @Vowneee

Below script works form me.
az monitor scheduled-query list --query "[?tags.regionspecific=='yes'].{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup}" -o tsv |  
while IFS=$'\t' read -r alert_name resource_group; do  
    echo "Disabled log query alert rule: $alert_name in resource group: $resource_group"  
done 

